# Bazel read temporary dynamically added file

Tags: python, bazel

I have a python script that downloads some json data and then uploads it somewehere else. The project is build and run using bazel and has the following simplified structure.

```
-scripts/
   -exported_file_1.json
   -main.py
-tests/
-BUILD
```

My issue is that when it comes to reading the exported files and loading them in memory, those files cannot be found using:

```
def get_filepath(filename):
    """Get the full path to file"""
    cwd = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return os.path.join(cwd, filename)
```

If I manually add a json file to the project structure, declare it in the BUILD file to be visible, do a bazel build then it works fine

```
py_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = [
        "main.py",
    ],
    data = ["scripts/exported_file_1.json"],
    python_version = "PY2",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [],
)
```

But how would one handle the case when your files are added dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) might work?

Something like:

```
import os
import glob

def get_json_files():
    cwd = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    p=f"{cwd}/*.json"
    return glob.glob(p)

for json_file in get_json_files():
    print(f"found file: {json_file}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `glob` in the `BUILD` file will allow the binary to find all `.json` files in the `scripts` directory:

```
py_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = [
        "scripts/main.py",
    ],
    data = glob(["scripts/*.json"]),
    python_version = "PY2",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [],
)
```

This would still require the JSON files to be downloaded and present in the `scripts/` directory when `bazel run :main` is executed.